# Replicate recent location

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like below

```
ID User Date        Location
1  Tom  6-Mar-2012  US
2  Tom  4-Feb-2012  UK
3  Tom  6-Jan-2012  Uk
4  Bob  6-Mar-2012  UK
5  Bob  4-Feb-2012  UK
6  Bob  6-Jan-2012  AUS
7  Dev  6-Mar-2012  US
8  Dev  4-Feb-2012  AUS
9  Nic  6-Jan-2012  US
```

I have to get each employee recent location in same table.

```
ID User Date        Location CurrentLocation
1  Tom  6-Mar-2012  US       US
2  Tom  4-Feb-2012  UK       US
3  Tom  6-Jan-2012  Uk       US
4  Bob  6-Mar-2012  UK       UK
5  Bob  4-Feb-2012  UK       UK
6  Bob  6-Jan-2012  AUS      UK
7  Dev  6-Mar-2012  US       US
8  Dev  4-Feb-2012  AUS      US
9  Nic  6-Jan-2012  US       US
```

I have tired with temp tables. can I get this done using single query. This is in middle of implementation. I have already created many temp tables.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *, CurrentLocation
from tbl x

outer apply
(
  select top 1 location as CurrentLocation
  from tbl
  where [user] = x.[user]
    and id <= x.id
  order by id

) y

order by id
```

Output:

```
ID      USER    DATE            LOCATION    CURRENTLOCATION
1       Tom     2012-03-06      US          US
2       Tom     2012-02-04      UK          US
3       Tom     2012-01-06      Uk          US
4       Bob     2012-03-06      UK          UK
5       Bob     2012-02-04      UK          UK
6       Bob     2012-01-06      AUS         UK
7       Dev     2012-03-06      US          US
8       Dev     2012-02-04      AUS         US
9       Nic     2012-01-06      US          US
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83a6a/7

Comment: Thanks a lot. Code worked like a charm. The only change I did was instead of taking ID, I took Date.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  id, 
  user,
  date,
  location,
  first_value(location) over(partition by user order by date desc) as current_location
from your_table s;
```

The above is valid only in Oracle.

This is my try in absence of first_value analytic function:

```
select 
  a.id, 
  a.usr,
  a.date,
  a.location,
  m.location as current_location
from 
  a
  join
   (select usr, location 
    from 
         (select usr, 
                 location, 
                 row_number() over(partition by usr order by date desc) as rnk
          from a
          )b
    where rnk = 1) m
   on m.usr = a.usr;
```

The m inner query contains the records with most recent user entries.
After this I make a join with this view, to obtain users's location.

See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87ba7/6) sqlfiddle test.

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for the ans. What should I replace with first_value

Comment: first_value is a valid function in sql-server.

Comment: I am getting error msg : Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'first_value' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: I didn't know that first_value is not implemented in MS SQL. It is on Oracle from years. Updated answer.

Comment: Its failing in the inner select. says : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'over'.

Comment: FIRST_VALUE is coming to SQL Server you just have to wait a little longer for 2012.